# repeating all values on all levels of a multi-level group by with aggregating function

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

I want get the count of colum3, but I want to group it by column1 and column2 whereby column2 has always the same (all) values of column2.

My current version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00d9d/1/0

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`column1` varchar(2), `column2` varchar(2), `column3` varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`)
VALUES
    ('aa', 'ba', 'ca'),
    ('aa', 'ba', 'cb'),
    ('aa', 'ba', 'cc'),
    ('aa', 'bb', 'ca'),
    ('aa', 'bb', 'cb'),
    ('aa', 'bc', 'ca'),
    ('aa', 'bc', 'cb'),
    ('aa', 'ba', 'ca'),
    ('ab', 'ba', 'cb'),
    ('ab', 'bc', 'ca')
;
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
         column1
         ,column2
         ,COUNT(column3) 
    FROM 
         table1
    GROUP BY 
         column1
         ,column2
```

Result

```
column1 column2 COUNT(column3)
aa  ba  4
aa  bb  2
aa  bc  2
ab  ba  1
ab  bc  1
```

**Now is my question how can I ensure that in all column1 aggregations are the same values of column2?** In case of the example I miss the

```
ab;bb;0
```

So I want that for every value of column1 I have the same set of values for column2. Which means in reality that a missing value gets filled up with 0 as count.

Comment: Please review [How to ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is a polite way of saying you have to invest a minimum amount of effort that is not evident here.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please revise.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Sorry, put it in a fiddle and added some further explanations. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: do not put code on offsite resources, put them INLINE in the question. And still not clear!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson like that?

Comment: @faulix90 - yes, good job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first generate all allowed values (column1 x column2) and then `left join` this with your query. Your query will provide the count where it knows it, otherwise you will just get 0:

```
select base1.column1, base2.column2, ifnull(YourQuery.cnt, 0)
from (select distinct column1 from table1) as base1 
cross join (select distinct column2 from table1) as base2
left join 
(SELECT column1,column2,COUNT(column3) as cnt
 FROM table1
 GROUP BY column1,column2
) as YourQuery
on YourQuery.column1 = base1.column1 and YourQuery.column2 = base2.column2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is basically to get all the combination and use join or union to fill the gap, Here i am using union all.

```
SELECT 
    column1
    ,column2
    ,count(column3) 
from (
select column1, column2, column3 from table1
union all
select column1,column2, null as column3
    from (select distinct column1 from table1 ) all_c1
    cross join ( select distinct column2 from table1) all_c2
)t group by column1, column2;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the solution of @Solarflare is a little bit more elegant (in my opinion).